# Преобразование двоичного числа в десятичное

Tags: javascript

Хочу реализовать перевод из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Если без готовых методов, то в цикле делить на 10 и запоминать остатки (это и будут десятичные цифры). Подводный камень -- LLONG_MIN. Если интересно вот [код на C](http://pastebin.com/zaNt0Y8C) (хотя, если в javascript нет беззнаковых типов, то толку от него Вам не будет)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
var binary = "1101000";
var digit = parseInt(binary, 2);
alert(digit);
```